# XAML Designer does not recognize custom control received from other machine?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I'm encountering a very weird problem. I have a simple custom control. It's built and shown fine on the designer in the machine in which I used to build the custom control.

Now when I send the dll file (of the custom control) to another machine running the same OS (Windows 10) and the same **Visual Studio 2015** version. After creating a test project, I can see that the control is shown fine in the XAML designer. Now if I send that dll back to the old machine, the control cannot be shown on the XAML designer (in the same test project), there is an error saying something like the dll is not recognized (inside xaml file). It's strange that I can still build and run that project and the control is shown fine at runtime.

I've checked all the possible properties of the project and they are all the same (between 2 machines). I don't really know what could be wrong here. Showing the custom control at design time is a requirement (for a designer to change the Style).

I hope someone here has experienced this issue before and can give me some suggestion. I doubt it may be some bug in the XAML designer (if so is there some work-around?)

Comment: You might want to check or try the following: 
How are you sending the dll around, it is via the XAP file? 
Are you using the same build configuration while running on both the machines? 
The best way to share dll is by creating a nuget package.

Comment: @bit the file is added to rar archive and sent via Skype, the build configuration is the same.

Comment: So to recap: a) control + dll built on machine 1 | b) control shows in designer on machine 2 (no new dll built) | c) control doesn't show anymore on machine 1? Have you tried cleaning the solution and restarting VS?

Comment: @Bart yes, what you described is correct. In fact the working machine 2 is of mine, while the machine building the control is of my co-worker. Currently I don't have access to that machine to test. I'll notify you after trying your suggestion (about cleaning and restarting). Thanks.